# How do I check for EACH individual letters in a string to see if they're alphabetical characters and not digits?

Tags: c++, string, digits, alphabetical

I'm working on an assignment (C++) where I have to have the user write out a string of text (Example input: 1hello22).

The task is to remove the digits one by one, in order too. So the output would be something like:

1. 1hello22
2. hello22
3. hello2
4. hello

How do I check each string letter in this loop? I can't get it to repeat itself. I'm assuming I need to use a nested for loop here, but I'm stuck and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
 cout<<"Enter some text:";
                            cin.ignore();
                                    getline(cin,userText);
                            system("clear");
                            for (q=0;q<=(userText.length());q++)
                            {
                                if (isalpha(userText.at(q))) //checks for alphabet
                                {
                                  q++;
                                  cout<<userText<<endl;
                                
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                  userText.erase(q,1); //gets rid of number
                                  q++;
                                  cout<<userText<<endl;
                                }
                        
                            }
```

Comment: Create a std:;stringstream. Parse through input string, if character is alphabetic, add the character to stringstream, else skip it.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by remove characters in order? And please format the code properly, it's difficult to read with so much indentation.

Comment: We have not learned how to use std::stringsteam :( you recommend I learn that way or what would you recommend? 

Also, sorry for indentation. The c/p did something weird from the IDE :( Will fix in a few hours, in bed now trying to catch my 3 hours of sleep. Thank you for your reply

Comment: I think you should first clarify what is meant by removing characters in order. Depending on the clarification, my initial suggestion can change.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has to many `q++` expressions. You should remove it from `for (q=0;q<=(userText.length());q++)` and from the `else` clause.

Besides of that, condition of the `for` loop must be `<` (not `<=`), because the last character of a string has the index `length() - 1`.